# value error expected 2D array got 1D array instead

Tags: python, opencv, valueerror

i am trying to do image classification using feature extraction. i have taken three feature to classify my dataset into. but on executing the code, i am getting a value error: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead. the code i am trying to execute is provided online. it is given in the following link
link for code: https://gogul.dev/software/image-classification-python
while running the code i encountered many errors which i corrected but while running the last module of the code under the heading: testing the classifier, i am getting 2 problems.

1. the test folder is created but is empty
2. value error: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

any help is appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: Could you upload your code here?

Comment: this is the link for the code:  https://gogul.dev/software/image-classification-python
in this link, the last module under the heading "Testing the best Classifier" is the code which is giving me the error

Comment: Make reproducible question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks. will try to do this and try to find the fault. much appreciated.